# Is branding yourself or another Jew allowed?

Tags: halacha, tattoo

Tattoos are forbidden.
How about [branding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_branding)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116808/discussion-on-question-by-hazoriz-is-branding-yourself-or-another-jew-allowed).

Comment: There are two aspects to it: harming oneself or another Jew is forbidden, tattoos were seen as idolatrous, but for branding, I didn't find any relation.

Answer (score 5):

In Rav Chaim Kanievsky's book שיח השדה (section דיני כתובת קעקע ;פתשגן הכתב, p.109) he writes that branding with a hot iron would be forbidden under the prohibition of מראית עין (giving the *appearance* of wrong-doing):

> אם שרט ולא מילא בצבע לדעת הרא"ש אין בזה גם איסור דרבנן וכ"נ דעת המאירי
> אבל מדברי התוס' נראה שיש בזה איסור דרבנן וכ"כ כמה אחרונים, וכ"ז בשרט
> ולא צבע או כגון אלו שמלבנין בברזל רותח ועושין בזה על בשרם כעין אותיות
> דאיכא מראית העין אבל בכותב בדיו על בשרו בלי שריטה אין שום ראי' מדברי
> התוס' לאסור ויש מי שמחמיר גם בזה ונראה דעל הצפורן אין להחמיר כלל ואפי'
> על בשרו המיקל לא הפסיד כיון שאינו כתב המתקיים כלל, ונראה דגם בשרט ולא
> צבע אין להחמיר אלא בעשה כעין אותיות או איזה ציור אבל לא בשריטה בעלמא
> (סי' י"ח)

.

Comment: Thank you May G-d Almighty bless you

Comment: Please consider transcribing the text for search engines and those visually impaired. Also perhaps the name of his kuntres